# How can I delete a security group from Active directory in .NET?

Tags: .net, active-directory

How can I delete a security group from Active directory in .NET?

Comment: What version of the framework?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In .NET 3.5 you can make use of the new namespace `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` and try the following:

```
var SecurityContext= new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);
var TheGroup = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(SecurityContext, "GROUP_NAME");
TheGroup.Delete();
```

Obviously the user under which the code is running needs to have delete permissions.